# Is there a similar folklore/parable in American/Western/European culture to the East Asian (Chinese?) parable on a Fox and a Tiger?

Tags: folklore

The Chinese/East Asian parable on a fox and a tiger goes like the following

A fox asking to be walking in front of a tiger brags about being a fearsome animal and exudes borrowed confidence from scared spectators, who are actually scared of the tiger behind the fox.

The tiger himself also believes the fox is indeed a scary animal simply because he does not realize whom the spectators are actually afraid of.

Is there a similar parable in the American, European or Western culture ?